# Obstructions to existence of finitely summable spectral triples

Tags: noncommutative-geometry, c-star-algebras, spectral-triples

Connes proved in his beautiful paper "Compact metric spaces, Fredholm modules, and hyperfiniteness" published in 1989 that if $(A,H,D)$ is a finitely summable spectral triple with a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$, then $A$ must have a tracial state. Here is the question: Is there an analogue of this result for 
non-unital spectral triples (for which $A$ is a non-unital  $C^*$-algebra and $D$ has locally compact resolvents)? What are the main obstructions for existence of finitely summable spectral triples?

Comment: According to MathSciNet, the paper you are referring to was published in 1989, not 1981: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1007407